# Passing list from views.py to template showing null value

Tags: html, django, django-views

I want to print certain attribute values in html. For this, I appended those values to a list (List) in views.py, and passed it via context to the corresponding template (viewperformance.html). When I print List in views.py, it gives a list of numbers, as expected. However, record in template prints no value at all.

VIEWS.PY

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
def edit_marks(request, course_code):

        # Some code irrelevant to the problem has been removed

        List = list()
        for i in range(len(registered_students)):
            m_id = registered_students[i]            
            s = score[i]

            rows = Marks.objects.filter(mid=m_id, exam_type=exam)
            num = Marks.objects.filter(mid=m_id, exam_type=exam).count()
            record = Marks.objects.filter(mid=m_id, exam_type=exam).values_list('marks', flat=True)

            List.append(list(record))

            if num==0:
                Marks.objects.create(
                    mid=m_id,
                    exam_type=exam,
                    marks=s
                    )
            else:
                Marks.objects.filter(mid=m_id, exam_type=exam).update(marks=s)

        print(List)

        return HttpResponse("Upload successful")  
        context= {'registered_students': registered_students, 'record':List}
    return render(request, 'coursemanagement/viewperformance.html', context)
```

viewperformance.html

```
{% load static %} {% block viewperformance %}

<div>

    <form class="ui large form" name="entermarks" id="entermarks" method="POST" action="/ocms/{{curriculum.course_code}}/edit_marks"> 

    {% csrf_token %}

    <select name="examtype" id = "examtype" style="width: 100px">
        <option value = "Quiz 1">Quiz 1</option>
        <option value = "Quiz 2">Quiz 2</option>
        <option value = "Mid Sem">Mid Sem</option>
        <option value = "End Sem">End sem</option>
    </select>

    <table class="ui very basic collapsing celled table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Students</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <p> 'Value of record : ' {{ record }} </p>
        {% for x in registered_students %}
            <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="content">
                <p style="text-align:center">{{x.student_id}}</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="enteredmarks" id="enteredmarks" required="true">
            </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="ui primary button" id="submit_marks" value="Upload">


    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'globals/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("#entermarks").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var friendForm = $(this);

            var posting = $.post( friendForm.attr('action'), friendForm.serialize() );
            // if success:
            posting.done(function(data) {
                alert('Upload Successful');
                // window.location = "/academic-procedures/main/";
            });
            // if failure
            posting.fail(function(data) {
                alert('Failed');
                // window.location = "/academic-procedures/main/";
            });
    });
});

</script>
```

`{{ record }}` gives no value at all, whereas List in views prints a list.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{% for list_obj in record %}
   {{list_obj|safe}}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{{record|safe}}
```

hope it helps for your problem